# Input::hasFile() not working

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am trying to check if the image that i am trying to upload is getthing processed, but when i try to use de Input::hasFile('upimg') to check it out it doesnt do anything. This is my form:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => array('uploadimage'), 'method' => 'POST')) !!}
                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('newimg', 'Choose Image to upload:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                        {!! Form::file('upimg', null) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('directory', 'Choose directory:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                        {!! Form::select('newimage', [ '' => 'none'] + $imagesdir , '', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>

                    {!! Form::submit('Upload', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}

                    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

And this is the code i am using to check the file:

```
public function doUpload()
{
   if (Input::hasFile('upimg')){
      echo 'uploaded';
   }; 
}
```

As you can see i am trying to check:

```
{!! Form::file('upimg', null) !!}
```

If i am not wrong its suppose to give mi back the echo but nothing happens. Why is this not working? what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure you have an `'file' => true` option in your form definition like below:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['uploadimage'], 'file' => true]) !!}
```

This option causes that your form will be render with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` option in HTML form tag. See documentation: [HTML enctype](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp)

You don't have to add `method => 'POST'` to your definition of form, because Laravel 5 sents forms with POST method by default.

Please let me know if this solution will not work for you.

For checking files on server side you can use methods of Request object like in documentation of Laravel: [Files in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#files)